# Cocoa: Strange behavior in Webkit Webview

Tags: iphone, macos, cocoa, webkit

Please enlighten me on this
I am loading a URl request

1. in safari and the page is loading as per the expectation
2. in UIWebview again the page is loading just fine
3. but when I load the same in a Cocoa webkit web view its not loading

not sure wether its not picking up the CSS or what but can you suggest me how can I overcome this?

Thanks in advance
Regards
Ankit

Comment: I would love to help...but can you show us some code, please?

Answer (score -1):

If you mean you're loading a local file, then yes it seems like the UIWebview doesn't load in any external files which is a bit frustrating. You just have to put everything in the html together. I made something with jQuery like this and just had to paste the entire jQuery.js file into the header! But daft, but it worked.

Comment: all the files are on web no local files